# Cloud SQL PostgresQL max_slot_wal_keep_size

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I could not find any way to limit replication slot in Cloud SQL postgres flags (`max_slot_wal_keep_size`) ? Is there any way I can limit it ?

Comment: have you tried `ALTER SYSTEM`?

Comment: won't resist db reboot @richyen :/

Comment: Unless Google did something weird with their fork, it should survive reboot.

Comment: hmm thanks @jjanes it thought it was only possible to update config through flags!

Comment: The flag `max_slot_wal_keep_size` is not available in the CloudSQL. But a feature request has already been made for it and there is no estimated time of release for this [feature](https://issuetracker.google.com/237574815).